# Problems implementing a deque class with output Deque<elements>

Tags: python, deque, notation

I'm attending a python course in university, where we should implement a deque class as an assignment. Now I've got some problems with the output an instance should give given in the docstring.

```
class Deque:
"""
>>> d = Deque()
>>> d
Deque<>

>>> d = d.append(1); d
Deque<1>

>>> d.append(2).prepend(0)   # allow for chaining of appending & prepending
Deque<0, 1, 2>
```

I have no idea how to achieve that an instance outputs this notation with the angle brackets.

Anybody got an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You work can work that out in the `__repr__` of the class.

As a simple example for an empty `Deque` instance:

```
>>> class Deque(object):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Deque<>'
...
>>> d = Deque()
>>> d
Deque<>
```

For a non-empty instance, you would simply format the returned string to include the contents of the instance.

Comment: Swapping `return 'Deque<>'` with `return 'Deque<' + ', '.join(self.INNER_CONTAINER) + '>'` would give the expected output for the full Deque, being INNER_CONTAINER the real name in your implementation where you are storing the Deque data

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `__repr__()` method; you can return a string formatted however you want.